# Remove Á character from the string in R

Tags: r

remove specifically Á from the string in R

```
x <- " HelloÂ  Sir how are u.Â  sdadas ";
plane.text=  gsub("Â","",x)
print(plane.text)
```

Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) :

shown error

Comment: Please check your locale settng as it is working for me

Comment: it has shown error in rshiny app